# jQuery .fadeTo(), how to fade not active links inside a menu?

Tags: jquery, menu, opacity, fadeto

I have an **ul li** menu which I want to make only the link with the :hover state with the opacity 1.0 the others will be set to something like 0.5. So each time the mouse is over the link it keeps its opacity, 1.0, and the others get their opacity changed to 0.5.
Is there a somenthing linke a **!:focus**, **!:hover** or !:active in jQuery? I see that there is **blur()** but it doesn't fit the case, I guess, because I need those that are not active and not those that lost focus.

--edited--
It work better with :not() instead of .not().
So this is working:

```
        $('#menu > li > a').bind({
            mouseenter: function(){
                $('#menu > li > a:not(:hover)').fadeTo('slow', 0.5).stop(true,true);
            },
            mouseleave: function() {
                $('#menu > li > a').fadeTo('slow', 1.0).stop(true,true);
            }
        });
```

Comment: So initially all links have opacity 1.0 when one is hovered only this one will keep its opacity and the others will receive 0.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey, did you try using .not()

should be something like this:

```
$('a').not(':hover');
```

[.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

Comment: `$('a:not(:hover)')` as alternative

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ***[not()](http://api.jquery.com/not)*** method combined with your :focus, :hover, or :active selectors.

**EDIT:**

<strike>Or if you want to, you can just use CSS like in this ***[working jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2ffNF/)***.</strike>

Based on your comments, here is what you want: ***[fade animated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2ffNF/2/)***.

Comment: Hum! So there is a not() but not in the way I've thought. :) Thank you. I try to learn how to use it. the first tries didn't work.

Comment: @tenshimsm - I edited my answer b/c after I was making you a jsFiddle for the not(), I thought why are you using jQuery for this anyway? CSS can do this much easier, and would be the preferred way, as it's less overhead.

Comment: Actually I tried with CSS, it's not what I want. The links must be opacity 1 while in normal status (without mouse over). The opacity 0.5 is only for the not hovered links, and keep 1.0 for the hovered one, to highlight it.

Comment: @tenshimsm - Ooooh, ok.  I gotcha.  I've edited my answer with the updated jsFiddle.  It animates the opacity using the not() method inside of a hover method.

Comment: Hey that's is what I want. I did it with :not() instead of .not().

Comment: @tenshimsm - Ok, that'll work too! Did you then add the animate() method for the fade effect?